# $1-\sqrt[n]{x_1}\sqrt[n-1]{x_2}\sqrt[n-2]{x_3}\sqrt[n-3]{x_4}...x_n=\sqrt[n]{y}$?

Tags: probability, statistics

$x_1,x_2,x_3...x_n,y$ are random variables satisfy uniform distribution in (0,1).

let A=$1-\sqrt[n]{x_1}\sqrt[n-1]{x_2}\sqrt[n-2]{x_3}\sqrt[n-3]{x_4}...x_n$,B=$\sqrt[n]{y}$

If A and B are random variables satisfying the same distribution?
It is strange that A has n variables but B has only one variable.

I got this from the formula about ordered random sequence in my another question:[The way to produce a random but ordered series of numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776443/the-way-to-produce-a-random-but-ordered-series-of-numbers)  In that question,A is got from a recursion formula while B is got directly from symmetry.A=B=$a_n$.